# Need to set 000 permission to specific hdfs data block through commandline

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to set the “000” permission to the specific block.

I used below command to find the block information:
su - hdfs -c "hdfs fsck -locations -files -blocks  /user/rohit/partition_filter_table/india.25.20.101.95000"

Now, I want to set permission to the block “blk_1073746617_5811” to “000”. Please let us know if there is any command or procedure to set the permissions for the same